# Detecting Login Fields

Tags: javascript, authentication

Would there be any way to detect login fields on ANY website using javascript?  IE and Firefox have the ability to 'remember' my username and password.  I would like to create a  script that replicated that functionality.  So for example, when presenting the login page for GMail, how could I 'find' the username and password field and get / set them?

Answer (score 5):

Basic outline:

1. Gather all password fields
2. Loop through all of them
3. On each iteration:

   1. Find the <form/> that the password field is a part of
   2. Find the first input field in the form that is 1) not the password field and 2) not anything other than type="text"
4. Return an array of all username/password pairs

---

Example output:

```
[ [ <input id="username" /> , <input type="password" id="pswd" /> ] ]
```

It will output an array of pairs, each pair contains a username and password node. Obviously, on most pages, you'll only get one pair because there's only one login section.

---

Here it is:

```
function getLoginFields() {
    var fieldPairs = [],
        pswd = (function(){
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
                len = inputs.length,
                ret = [];
            while (len--) {
                if (inputs[len].type === 'password') {
                    ret[ret.length] = inputs[len];
                }
            }
            return ret;
        })(),
        pswdLength = pswd.length,
        parentForm = function(elem) {
            while (elem.parentNode) {
                if(elem.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'form') {
                    return elem.parentNode;
                }
                elem = elem.parentNode;
            }
        };
    while (pswdLength--) {
        var curPswdField = pswd[pswdLength],
            parentForm = parentForm(curPswdField),
            curField = curPswdField;
        if (parentForm) {
            var inputs = parentForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i] !== curPswdField && inputs[i].type === 'text') {
                    fieldPairs[fieldPairs.length] = [inputs[i], curPswdField];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fieldPairs;
}

// Usage:
var loginFields = getLoginFields()[0]; // or loop through results.
```

---

Tested successfully on Yahoo, Amazon, Google, Youtube... (various account/login pages)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Locate the username field in the form by searching backwards
// from the first passwordfield, assume the first text field is the
// username. We might not find a username field if the user is
// already logged in to the site.
for (var i = pwFields[0].index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (form.elements[i].type == "text") {
    usernameField = form.elements[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

This is how firefox does: http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/src/nsLoginManager.js#655

Answer (score 2):

Well one method (that I'm almost sure one of the browsers is using) would be to find the first <input type="password">, and then search for the <input type="text"> before it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the IE and Firefox password detection stuff is based loosely on the name of the field, that is, it prompts you if you have the word username and/or password in the id.

if your using jQuery you could use something like.

```
$('input[id*=username]').css('background', 'red');
// or
$('input[id*=password]').css('background', 'red');
```

Additionally, you can check for any password fields using jQuery by

```
$(':password').css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: This is not feasible, as several websites obfuscate the name such as *uname*, *usrname*, *usr_name*, *login*.

Answer (score 0):

I think User/Password remember feature in browsers is triggered by a presence of a password-type input field in the form.

Next thing you'd have to do is to look for the most common login fields `name`d 'login', 'user', 'username', 'j_username' (in case there's a [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service)-based site). If you don't, just store all text input fields. ;)